# I cannot activate my virtual environment from anaconda into vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, miniconda

I created a virtual environment in miniconda3

I then installed all the the packages I wanted to use for my project ( pip install snowflake snowpark-python streamlit)

Afterwards, I opended up VsCode and used the python interpreter and selected my virtual environment.

Afterwards when I try to run a command like **"streamlit hello"**  it shows that the package was not installed.

However when I run the same command in my minicondaPrompt it works perfectly fine.

I then realized I had to activate the environment aswell in my vscode terminal. Here's where the problem occurs

I use the command stenv\Scripts\activate.bat
and I get the error

stenv\Scripts\activate.bat : The module 'stenv' could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module stenv'.
At line:1 char:1

- stenv\Scripts\activate.bat
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (stenv\Scripts\activate.bat:String) [], CommandNotFoundException       
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoLoadModule
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Select the **Conda** environment interpreter in `Selecting Interpreter` panel.

   [image]
2. The selected interpreter version will be displayed in the lower right corner

   [image]
3. Without modifying this default setting, the new terminal will automatically activate the environment.

   ```
   "python.terminal.activateEnvironment": false
   ```

   [image]

***You don't have to use the command to operate at the terminal. It is more convenient to install [Python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) extension and use it to execute the script.***

*There are more information here:*

- *https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial*
- *https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments*
- *https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html*